# How do I transform my dataframe in python so that it's a different shape?

Tags: python, dataframe, transform, transformation

**I have a dataframe in python which is of the format:**

[image]

**I would like to transform my dataframe so that it looks like the image below instead:**

[image]

**Any guidance would be helpful. Thanks**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're calling it a dataframe, I'm going to assume you are using `pandas` to manipulate the data. In which case, you could do something like this using [melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html):

--- data.csv

```
Name,Applied,Review,Interview 1,Interview 2,Interview 3,Hire,Department
Jed,15/09/2022,30/11/2022,10/01/2023,23/01/2023,29/01/2023,04/02/2023,Technology
Chloe,19/10/2022,02/12/2022,10/12/2022,21/12/2022,05/01/2023,10/01/2023,Commercial
```

--- python script

```py
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df = df.melt(id_vars=['Name','Department'], var_name='Stage',value_name='Stage Date')
df = df.sort_values(by='Name')
```

--- dataframe contents

```py
     Name  Department        Stage  Stage Date
1   Chloe  Commercial      Applied  19/10/2022
3   Chloe  Commercial       Review  02/12/2022
5   Chloe  Commercial  Interview 1  10/12/2022
7   Chloe  Commercial  Interview 2  21/12/2022
9   Chloe  Commercial  Interview 3  05/01/2023
11  Chloe  Commercial         Hire  10/01/2023
0     Jed  Technology      Applied  15/09/2022
2     Jed  Technology       Review  30/11/2022
4     Jed  Technology  Interview 1  10/01/2023
6     Jed  Technology  Interview 2  23/01/2023
8     Jed  Technology  Interview 3  29/01/2023
10    Jed  Technology         Hire  04/02/2023
```